# Names of the sections in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using the plain book style. The problem is that I would like to see in the table of contents the long names of chapters, sections and subsections:

```
\chapter[shortname]{longname}
\section[shortname]{longmane}
```

To push LaTeX to use the long names of the chapters (or parts) I can modify the line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
```

in the `book.cls` file and replace the number of the argument to `#2`

But there is no `\addcontentsline{toc}...` lines in the *.sty file for sections, subsection etc.

I have read the previous topics on similar problems, such as

- [Section title in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118735/section-title-in-the-table-of-contents)

and the problem itself is solved at the moment, but how the format of `\addcontentsline` commands is defined for sections and subsections in LaTeX files by default? I can not find it!

Comment: Since the only purpose of the short title is to be put in the table of contents, why are you even creating them?

Answer (score 1):

The `\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}` package will place the long section titles in the table of contents.

As for the chapter, in case you just need the short version for the header, set it separately.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Longchap}
    \chaptermark{shortchap}

    \section[short]{long}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow :) Thanks allot! It works fine. But could I somehow edit the default style? To reach the same effect?

Comment: @DmitryZlenko Why do you want to do this? You could read the source of the `titlesec` package and see how they do it. But please remember: to adhere the latex licence, don't just modify `book.cls` but rename it.

Comment: Yes. I already has my own one cls :) Thanks for the advice. I not need it, I just want to understand.